# flask_mysqldb SQL str for execution not working

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am using flask and flask_mysqldb for a app. However, I tried to execute a simple query with a column alias. It does not work if I construct my query using some other variables, as below:

```
alias = "x"
sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS " + alias + " FROM DBTable"

db   = MySQL(app)
conn = db.connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute (sql)
```

I got an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ..."

However, if I simply replace the 2nd code line to `sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS x FROM DBTable"`, it works. I have checked that the two `sql` variables have the same value. So this is super confusing to me.

Does anyone know the reason behind the error?

Comment: I tested your code and it does not produce a syntax error. Despite what ChatGPT told you, it's not necessary to quote a column alias if it follows normal [identifier format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) (the alias `x` is just fine as an identifier). I think something else was the cause of your syntax error, and you solved it by accident as you were making the other change.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was an issue and can be fixed by adding single quote (on my pc). I am using Visual Studio Code editor. It may depend on editor or other environment configurations I guess, but it seems that adding single quotes is the safer way.   ps. I understand that we don't need single quotes if running query interactively in Workbench, if that is what you tried.

Comment: I tried it by writing a short Python script, and executing it from the command-line with `python3 test.py`

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved (thanks ChatGPT!) The column alias for MySQL needs to include single quotes as below:

```
sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS '" + alias + "' FROM DBTable"
```

Sometimes the single quotes will be automatically added if you forgot to specify it, which is the case in my 2nd `example sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS x FROM DBTable"`.